# How to expand layout in recycler view while clicking on it

Tags: java, android

I have CardView that contain ImageView (size 100dp), TextView X3 that have a lot of text.
In recycler view , while creating the item view in my onBindViewHolder I'm setting the TextView's to visibility GONE to hide them, and displaying only image view.

While I'm clicking on it , I need to set visibility of TextViews to VISIBLE , but to show the text correctly i need to expand the item view ( To make it largest ).
I can do it bu setting the height and width to wrap-content, but because my grid layout has 3 item in row, so the ItemView expands only to hight.

How to make selected ItemView overlapping other items?

Please see attachments in the end of the post.

That what i have now:

My adapter:

```
public class LightsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LightsAdapter.LightsViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Light> lights;
    private OnLightImageClickListener onLightImageClickListener;
    private int selected = -1;
    private Light light;

    public LightsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Light> lights) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lights = lights;
    }

    public interface OnLightImageClickListener {
        void onLightImageClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnLightImageClickListener(OnLightImageClickListener onLightImageClickListener) {
        this.onLightImageClickListener = onLightImageClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public LightsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lights_item, parent, false);
        return new LightsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LightsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        light = lights.get(position);
        holder.rootItemView.setTag(position);
        holder.TVlightTitle.setText(light.getLampTitle());
        holder.TVLightDesc.setText(light.getLampDesc());
        holder.TVLightType.setText(String.valueOf(light.getLampType()));
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(light.getLampImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .override(200, 200)
                .into(holder.IVLightImage);
//        setBackGround(holder);
        hideLightInfo(holder);

        if (position == selected) {
            showLightInfo(holder);
        } else {
            hideLightInfo(holder);

        }
        holder.rootItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = (int) view.getTag();
                selected = position;
                if (onLightImageClickListener != null) {
                    onLightImageClickListener.onLightImageClick(position);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lights.size();
    }

    public class LightsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView TVlightTitle;
        private TextView TVLightDesc;
        private TextView TVLightType;
        private ImageView IVLightImage;
        private CardView rootItemView;

        public LightsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            TVlightTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightTitle);
            TVLightDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightDesc);
            TVLightType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightType);
            IVLightImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightImage);
            rootItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootItemView);
        }
    }

    public void hideLightInfo(LightsViewHolder holder) {
        holder.TVlightTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.TVLightDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.TVLightType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.IVLightImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void showLightInfo(LightsViewHolder holder) {
        holder.TVlightTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.TVLightDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.TVLightType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.IVLightImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void setBackGround(LightsViewHolder holder) {
        if (light.getLampType() == 1) {
            holder.rootItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            holder.rootItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
```

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootItemView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lightTitle"
            tools:text="lightTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lightDesc"
            tools:text="lightDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lightType"
            tools:text="lightType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lightImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

In this 2 images you can see what I have now.
How to make the item largest and overlapping other items while clicking?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using to display the content of the grid item is wrong.

You should use either the [bottom sheet](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427) or can use [popupwindow](https://www.tatnorix.in/custom-tooltip-tutorial-in-android/) with an anchor view. That will look good and your content will be rendered properly.